# Passing parameters : Adb extras to android activity

Tags: c#, android, adb

Newbee to ADB

I wanted to do the following in my project.

1> Start with a nice GUI with some buttons like below (WPF c#) (achieved)

1> Install button to install apk (achieved)

2> Button to run apk (achieved)

3> Pass certain parameters to the android activity by using 'adb extras' (!PROBLEMS)

4> Capture the output into c# program (WPF GUI) (achieved)

Can anyone please give me an example to pass parameters to a activity in android using adb extras. Pass parameters to activity and how would you fetch these values in android activity. (Consider if i want to send two strings as extras to activity through ADB and extract them  concatenate them in the android program.  I dont find any clear answer for this online or an example. I have tried many things without results.

Responses in this regard would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass those Strings as extras to your activity like this:

```
adb shell am start -n com.yourpackage/com.yourpackage.YourActivity --es extraKey extraValue
```

And in your activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
private String extraValue;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        extraValue = bundle.getString("extraKey");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i do like this: ask the use in a console application to enter a value to sent as extra value, store this in a variable and pass this variable to :                                                      am start -n com.yourpackage/com.yourpackage.YourActivity --es extraKey extraValue                                                          here extraValue = my variable name in which the value entered by the user is used